# How can I combine an observable that returns a collection with a new observable per item?

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

Current schema in firebase (that is relevant to this issue):
- Users
- Parties
- Invitation
    - UserId
    - PartyId

The goal is "join" the users into the invitation they belong to.

The ugly way which works is to just nest the calls but I know that cannot be the right way. I am kinda new to the RxJS stuff but feel like there has to be a way to do this in a more concise manner.

The ugly...

```js
const attendees = [];
this.invitationStore.collection$((ref) => ref.where('partyId', '==', partyId)) // Observable<Invitation[]>
  .subscribe((invitations: Invitation[]) => {
    invitations.map((invite: Invitation) => {
      this.userStore.doc$(invite.userId) // Observable<User>
        .subscribe((user: User) => {
          // combine invite & user
          invite.user = user;
          attendees.push(invite);
        });
    });
  });
```

I've tried this but it never logs anything

```js
this.getInvitations(partyId).pipe(
  map((invites: Invitation[]) => invites.map((invite: Invitation) => invite.userId)),
  switchMap((userIds: string[]) => forkJoin(userIds.map((id: string) => this.getUser(id))))
).subscribe((data: any) => console.log(data)); // nothing logs here

getInvitations(partyId: string): Observable<Invitation[]> {
  return this.invitationStore.collection$((ref) => ref.where('partyId', '==', partyId));
}

getUser(userId: string): Observable<User> {
  return this.userStore.doc$(userId);
}
```

I am using rxjs 6

Comment: what does this.userStore.doc$(userId) if not found? not emitting anything or complete itself as observable?

Comment: But that's not how forkJoin works... This is why it returns nothing when you subscribe to it

Comment: The this.userStore.doc$(userId) returns an observable (from firebase valueChanges) method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `mergeMap` the results of `forkJoin` for every invitation:

```
interface Invitation {
    userId: number;
}

interface User {
    name: string;
}

interface MappedInvitation {
    userId;
    user: User;
}

function getInvitations(): Observable<Invitation[]> {
    return;
}

function getUser(userId): Observable<User> {
    return;
}

function getMappedInvitations(): Observable<MappedInvitation[]> {
  return getInvitations().pipe(
    mergeMap(invitations => {
      return forkJoin(
        invitations.map(invitation =>
          getUser(invitation.userId).pipe(
            map(user => {
              const mappedInvitation: MappedInvitation = {
                user: user,
                userId: invitation.userId
              };
              return mappedInvitation;
            })
          )
        )
      );
    })
  );
}
```

If your `getUser` stream never completes, you might want to use `combineLatest` instead. Or `pipe(take(1))` with forkJoin.

Comment: Gonna give this a try and I will report back. Thanks!